# Printing raw EPL2 to Zebra Thermal from Internet Explorer

Tags: php, windows, internet-explorer, printing, zebra-printers

I've found that I can print raw EPL2 commands to my Zebra 2844 (UPS) from Windows apps like Notepad and WordPad and get a nicely printed label using the Generic / Text driver in XP (couldn't get the actual Zebra drivers to do this much). But for some reason, I can **not** get it to print from IE8 (which is necessary for my php application). Nor from Firefox for that matter. When I print, the file goes to the printer's queue and quickly disappears. Nothing is printed.

I'm setting the header to Content-type: text/plain in php. But I've also tried loading the text file directly from the Desktop and printing with no luck.

Anyone run into this issue and have a solution? Perhaps there is a nuance in printing from a web browser that I'm not taking into consideration?

Comment: Try printing to a file and see what the browser is adding to the stream. That might give you a clue.

Comment: That's a great idea! In comparing print file outputs, IE is adding a space after each line of code, and Notepad has an extra non-printing character before the whole thing, plus a few extra at the end. IE prints these too, but not as many. I guess I'll experiment further.

Comment: 90% certain that the space at the end of the line is the issue. The printer just doesn't like that. Now to figure out how to eliminate it.

Comment: How are you sending it to the printer via the web app?

Comment: With the browser. I gave up on IE8 and used Opera instead. I may do some testing to see if IE9 works any differently.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a way to get past the Windows Print layer, try this: http://code.google.com/p/jzebra/

It is a java applet that once you accept the security certificate can access the printer natively